# How to find the name of a property used in object initialization in a delegate?

Tags: c#, lambda, func

I have a delegate which takes an object as a parameter and  returns an new object with a certain property set to the value of a certain property of the object passed in.

example:

```
ObjA => new ObjB { Foo = ObjA.Bar, Foo1 = ObjA.Bar1 }
```

how can I get find the name of the property which Foo is set to (in this example, that would be ObjA.Bar)?

I have a feeling this involves getting and analyzing the expression tree, but I'm not sure how to do that or if it's necessary here.

Comment: "_how can I get find the name of the property which Foo is set to (in this example, that would be ObjA.Bar)?_" - why do you want to know this?

Comment: "_I have a feeling this involves getting and analyzing the expression tree, but I'm not sure how to do that or if it's necessary here._" - you can only do that if you're using `Expression<Func<X,Y>>` - if you aren't using `Expression<>` then you can't analyze the expression tree.

Comment: @Dai the reason is because I have many delegates with the same signature, and each one sets `Foo` to a different property of `ObjA`. Sometimes the value of that property causes a runtime exception if I don't do some string manipulation first, but I can't do that string manipulation if I don't know which property of `ObjA` was causing the exception.

Comment: "_the reason is because I have many delegates_" - why are you doing that? how is this system meant to work? None of this sounds right to me and it sounds like someone decided to do something a very roundabout way...

Comment: @Dai not everyone implements logging framework or CMS, there is still large number of people going for automapper implementation as their second project. Looks pretty reasonable option to me (assuming OP is implementing a variation of automapper for educational purposes)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov No-one said anything about logging, CMS or AutoMapper...

Comment: @Dai you're correct that it doesn't sound right. The code I'm working on was designed to compensate for a terrible database design where information that should have used a join table is stored in one table with about twenty or thirty columns repeating the same four datapoints for many different clients.
It's silly and backwards, but not something that can be changed right now because too many production systems are using it. Meanwhile we have a dictionary which maps clients to a delegate that returns an object with the values from their relevant columns on the table.

Comment: "but I can't do that string manipulation if I don't know which property of ObjA was causing the exception." - that doesn't sound like something that needs to be done at runtime. You must already know which properties cause the exception, so just process them in the delegate assignment whenever referred or create a manipulated property in the `ObjA` definition to use instead. You are writing the code that creates the delegates, right?